# How to compare two different time values

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, time, mfc

I want to check if the system time is at specific value. Like if the time is 11:15 am or not or I can use if the time is later than 11:00 am.

I tried to use

```
   CTime CurrentTime = CTime::GetCurrentTime();
```

but could not figure out how to compare it.

Thanks

Comment: CTime has comparison operators. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fww7f4h3%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: @drescherjm thanks, I saw that but how can i interpret if the time is 11:00 am ? Then I think I can compare current time and the 11:00 am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a additional CTime object([Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/b6989cds%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)):

```
CTime CurrentTime=CTime::GetCurrentTime();

if(CurrentTime==CTime(2013,11,1,20,15,00))
{
    // Do that...
    Sleep(0);
}
```

But it is always safer to compare against a timespan:

```
if((CurrentTime>CTime(2013,11,1,20,15,00))&&(CurrentTime<CTime(2013,11,1,20,15,05)))
{
    // Do that...
    Sleep(0);
}
```

In that case I took a span of 5 seconds. Usually you will never hit the exact time, so the second example is safer.

And at least, to answer your question, if you want to know when its past 11:00

```
if(CurrentTime>CTime(CurrentTime.GetYear(),CurrentTime.GetMonth(),CurrentTime.GetDay(),11,00,00))
{
   // Uhh yeah, past 11:00
}
```

Comment: Not necessarily a span, but the event of BEFORE that time to AFTER that time.  Even if you have an "epsilon" of 1 second, there is still a chance you could be tasked-out of the processor for that amount of time (e.g. waiting on an I/O operation on a floppy disk).   There is no "epsilon" value guaranteed to be big enough, so just detect the transition from "before" the mark to "after".

Comment: Thanks @Martin, is this 24h format or should I check am/pm seperately?

Comment: @franji1 You are totally right, I added a sample for that. I tried to stick close to the question.

Comment: @user2937812, it is 24h.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer COleDateTime. The time is represented as a double.
Full numbers represent the days since what ever. The fraction represents the time of day, so 0.5 ist noon 0.75 is 6pm...

Easy for calculations and easy to compare. There is also a COleDateTimeSpan helper class.