# How to compare two "times" in C++ either with chrono or Ctime?

Tags: c++, time, compare, c++-chrono, ctime

I am struggling with this problem to compare to point of times in c++  whether with `"chrono"` or `"Ctime`". 
I would appreciate if any one could help me with this issue.

Comment: Doesn't this solve your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733222/how-to-compare-two-different-time-values

Answer (score 0):

[`std::chrono::time_point`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point) is [comparable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point/operator_cmp) in C++11